# Instagram, Curl, PHP, Problem with status code and Conditions

Tags: php, if-statement, curl, request, php-curl

I want to check in the Instagram, if account exists, do something.
But if accounts doesn't exist, echo error.

I am creating a condition with checking status code. Here is a code:

```
<?php

$username = 'ddddddmsdklmklmfklmfklsd';
$url = 'https://instagram.com/'.$username.'/';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json') );
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if ($httpcode == 200) {
    echo $httpcode;
}else{
    echo $httpcode;
}

?>
```

On local server I get 404, but on real server(hosting) I get 200. Why?

Comment: I cannot duplicate it. You may want to echo/var_dump the $data to see what it's sending back.

Comment: I want to know why on the hosting I get 200, but on locale server I get 404

Comment: Hard to tell without being to duplicate it, which is why I suggested examining the data that it's sending back.

Comment: You are probably getting the login page returned (with a status code 200, because that _does_ exist), because IG has recognized that your request did not come from a normal browser. There's a lot of possible reasons for that - and you will likely not be able to cover them all; after all IG is actively working against you here (they do not _want_ you to do the thing you are trying to do here, so they have implemented measures against it.)

Comment: How can I check if the account exists? using php